# Проблема с кодировкой в скрипте PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

Добрый день программисты. Подскажите пожалуйста почему на выводе скрипта на экран вместо букв кракозябры? Если аргументом пишу латиницей, все нормально, если кириллицей кракозябры.

```
function abbrevName($name): string
{
  $arr = explode(" ", ucwords($name));

  return substr($arr[0],0,1).".".substr($arr[1],0,1);
}
echo abbrevName('джон смит')."<br><hr>";
```

Comment: Дубликатов должно быть море. Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%5B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%5D) [php][кодировка].

Comment: Везде проблемы с выводом из базы данных, у меня просто строка

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Задача решилась. Нужно было подобрать функции, которые работают с разными кодировками

```
function abbrevName($name): string
{
  $arr = explode(" ", mb_convert_case($name,MB_CASE_TITLE));

  return mb_substr($arr[0],0,1).".".mb_substr($arr[1],0,1);
}
echo abbrevName('джон смит');
```

Comment: Ужаснейший ответ. Хуже некуда. Лучше удалите его. Достаточно просто задать кодировку на всей странице, а не прыгать с бубном возле костра и перекодировать каждую строку

Comment: @SemyonBayandin, ну, удалять незачем. Ответ — это ответ. Плохой ответ — тоже ответ.

Comment: @Глеб вот как раз-таки плохие ответы и не надо здесь постить, если мы хотим уменьшить количество говнокода в мире

Comment: @SemyonBayandin в противовес ужаснейшему ответу вы можете написать отличнейший ответ

Comment: @АлексейР плодить ещё один дубликат из миллиарда других точно таких же ответов?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin а можно узнать как "задание кодировки на всей странице" решит проблему применения `ucwords` и `substr` на строках с русскими символами?

Comment: ucwords тут если только самому метод написать. `substr` - `mb_substr`

Comment: @SemyonBayandin ну так это и сделал ТС, а ты написал, что ужаснейший ответ и начал предлагать изменить кодировку страницы...

Comment: господа, я перепробовал разные кодировки на странице, это не работает, поэтому сюда писал.

Comment: А дело и не в кодировках. По-хорошему, @SemyonBayandin  должен устыдиться, и удалить свой нелепый комментарий, чтобы не сбивать людей с толку. Другое дело, что вопрос - явный дубликат, но всем лень искать, чтобы закрыть его как полагается.

Comment: Если дубликат покажите ссылку на такую же тему, я не нашел.

Comment: На самом деле использование функций конвертации регистра символов Unicode в PHP даже в нынешнем PHP 8.3 - плохая идея, и использовать её нужно осторожно. С кириллицей еще все прокатит, но в общем случае, если сайт много-языковой, лучше сразу иметь две строки отдельно в нижнем и верхнем регистре! На поведение функции до сих пор не влияют региональные настройки. Разрабы PHP просто криворукие и уже 10 лет в ответ на многочисленные жалобы программистов, не могут внедрить региональные настройки в функции mb или iconv. Еще раз - с кириллицей - все прокатит. В общем случае - будет белиберда.